# Regex works in simulator but fails in C# implementation. What am I missing?

Tags: c#, regex

This is the Regex I wrote and it works in the debugger tool:

```
(<a href="(http:\/\/store-assets.aapg.org\/documents\/previews\/\S+\/\S+\.pdf)".+<\/a>)
```

[image]

But when I try it inside a Razor template it fails to get a match (code generated by Regex101.com:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Example
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string pattern = @"(<a href=""(http:\/\/store-assets.aapg.org\/documents\/previews\/\S+\/\S+\.pdf)"".+<\/a>)";
        string input = @"<div class=""dnnClear""><div itemprop=""description""> <b>This hardcover book contains extended abstracts of the articles. Full articles are on the included DVD.</b> <p></p> 

<a href=""http://store-assets.aapg.org/documents/authors/M110pc1268AbouttheEditors.pdf"" target=""_blank"">About the Editors</a>
<p></p>
<a href=""http://store-assets.aapg.org/documents/toc/M110TOCpc1268.pdf"" target=""_blank"">Table of Contents</a></div> <div class=""store-item-desc dnnClear"">AAPG Memoir 110

<p></p>
<a href=""http://store-assets.aapg.org/documents/previews/1268M110/CHAPTER01.pdf"" target=""_blank"">View the first chapter</a></div></div>";
        RegexOptions options = RegexOptions.Multiline;

        foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(input, pattern, options))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("'{0}' found at index {1}.", m.Value, m.Index);
        }
    }
}
```

I adapted it to my Razor template as follows -- Doesn't work:

```
String srcstr3 = Web_Description;
String matchpattern3 = @"(<a href=""(http:\/\/store-assets.aapg.org\/documents\/previews\/\S+\/\S+\.pdf)"".+<\/a>)";
RegexOptions options3 = RegexOptions.IgnoreCase;
var pattern3 = new Regex(matchpattern3, options3);
Match match3 = pattern3.Match(srcstr3);
var chapter = (match3.Success) ? match3.Groups[2].Value : "did not match";
```

What am I missing? Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Please define *doesn't work*.

Comment: It works on c# fiddle https://dotnetfiddle.net/A59BO3. What do you expect ? What is wrong with it ?

Comment: and even your second block of code works: https://dotnetfiddle.net/gQNTkm.

Comment: Are you sure `srcstr3` contains the same string as  `var input` do?

Comment: It's not getting a match in Razor for some reason.

Comment: Please inspect your `String srcstr3 = Web_Description;`, what does it contains?

Comment: @DragandDrop, it seems to NOT contain the HTML I thought it contained... Thanks for the reality check! (Feeling kinda stupid right now...)

Comment: Thank you also @DanWilson, that was truly amazing how quickly you guys came to help!

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @DragandDrop I realized HTML was different in Razor than in the debugging tool.